# Google Map not displaying after clicking button

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-maps, events, visible

I have been trying to hide Google Maps on my site (which is inside a div). I used the following in a "send" Button event called: function showPoint()

```
document.getElementById('GMap1').style.display = 'block';
```

But nothing happens when I click the send button which is suppose to execute this event.

I was able to hide the map with:

```
<div id="GMap1" style="height: 300px; width:300px; visibility:hidden;"  ></div>
```

Only problem is displaying it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you must modify the `visibility`, not the `display`:

```
document.getElementById('GMap1').style.visibility= 'visible';
```